# Control spacing within

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to build a small listing of terms with definitions. Below is a MWE. I want the items after the `\indent`s to line up.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

FOV \indent Field of View

A \indent  Half-Angle of FOV (subscripts apply)

\end{document}
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `tabbing`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing} 
    \hspace{1cm} \=  \kill  
    FOV \> Field of View \\
    A \>  Half-Angle of FOV (subscripts apply)  
 \end{tabbing}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [**eqlist**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqlist) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqlist}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqlist}[\eqlistinit \labelsep 2em]
    \item[FOV] Field of View
    \item[A] Half-Angle of FOV (subscripts apply)
    \item[LONGER] a slightly longer item
\end{eqlist}
\end{document}
```

It automatically aligns all definitions according to the longest term that you want to define. Additionally, use the value behind `\labelsep` to set the distance (the "gap") between the end of the longest term and the begin of its definition.

There are a lot of other options which you can find in the [documentation of the package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/eqlist/eqlist.pdf).

[image]